# How do I parse PurpleAir JSON in flutter?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

So I'm trying to parse PurpleAir JSON from [here](https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=15130).

Using [this documentation](https://github.com/bomeara/purpleairpy/blob/master/api.md).

I am having trouble getting access to the data I really want, for example, the live 2.5 AQI reading.

This is my code that returns the parsed JSON data in a string, all I can get is the map version, can someone tell me how I can modify this code to get the other data?(basically, what do I put in the jsonResponse brackets to get the element labeled /v./)

```
Future<String> sensorTest() async{
  var url = "https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=15130";
  var response =  await http.get(url);//Parses it
   if (response.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      var aqi = jsonResponse['mapVersion']; 
      String output = "Map Version: "+aqi;
      return output;
   }
   else{
     return "Something is wrong";
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactor the code to make more readable, it worked for me, with the `print` I get:

> Map Version: 0.72

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<String> sensorTest() async {
    const String url = 'https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=15130';
    final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final dynamic jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final dynamic aqi = jsonResponse['mapVersion'];
      final String output = 'Map Version: $aqi';
      print(output);
      return output;
    } else
      return 'Something is wrong';
  }
```

In order to get the `v`, you can do like so:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<String> sensorTest() async {
    const String url = 'https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=15130';
    final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final dynamic jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final dynamic aqi = jsonResponse['results'][0]['Stats']['v'];
      final String v = 'V: $aqi';
      print(v);
      return v;
    } else
      return 'Something is wrong';
  }
```

Comment: That's not my problem, I can get the map version just fine, I need to get the 2.5 aqi reading live